# What are some important results of type theory?

Tags: math-history, type-theory

It would be great to have an overview of some of the most important results in type theory.

What are in your opinion some of the most important results/widely applicable results in type theory everyone should know about?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered properly. Type theory is a broad discipline with connections to many other fields. You should add details about what kind of information you are looking for and what you background or interest in type theory is.

Comment: Sure, my background is computer science though I enjoy mathematics as well. One of the importent theorems for myself would be that in HM type checking and type inference is decidable, making it one of the strongest type theories with this property.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question is a bit inappropriate.  But I would like to say that a part of type theory is the use of computer-assisted proof, for example, the LEAN system.  In my case it is the only approach I have had to this area. I recommend [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376839/what-makes-dependent-type-theory-more-suitable-than-set-theory-for-proof-assista) in MO.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to **Curry-Howard Correspondence**, and **Normalization Theorems**, in which the former establishes a deep connection between systems of formal logic and computational type systems, and the latter state that every valid term (or proof) in a given type system can be reduced to a normal form, which cannot be simplified further.